# backbone collection has empty models after fetch

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, model

I have a backbone model with embedded collection and i use 'parse' function:

```
var OrderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot:'/handlers/order',
   defaults:{
      'id':'',
      'name': '',
      'history': new HistoryCollection()
   },
   parse: function(response){
      this.set({'id': response.id});
      this.set({'name': response.name});
      var historyList = new HistoryCollection();
      historyList.add(response.history);
      this.set({history: historyList});
   }
})
```

Collection

```
var OrderCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/handlers/orders/',
    model: OrderModel,
    parse:function(response){
        return response;
    }
});
```

Code from view:

```
var c = new OrderCollection();
    this.collection.fetch().complete(function(){
    console.log(c);
});
```

my server returns JSON, by models are not populated.
But if I remove 'parse' function from OrderModel all works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone expects a return from the parse function, try instead of setting your models values just returning the json you want,

```
parse: function(response){
  var historyList = new HistoryCollection();
  historyList.add(response.history);
  return {
    'id': response.id,
    'name': response.name,
    history: historyList
  };
}
```